# Export dynamodb on demand data table by data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to export data from dynamoDb to S3 by using data pipeline. My table is on-demand provisioned and contains data of 10gb. How much rcu it would consume? Is there a way I could reduce the scaling of the rcu and would eventually increase the time for transfer?

Answer (score 0):

You can change on-demand <-> provisioned capacity any time. You should do it since provisioned is cheaper, also you hardset rcu for provisioned, which you want

Comment: I thought so, but I doing this for prod account so there is possibility of throttling in changing to provisioned type.

Comment: If that's your worry. You can create a copy of your table and use that copy

Answer (score 0):

As another option, DynamoDB recently released a new feature to export your data to an S3 bucket. It supports DynamoDB JSON and Amazon Ion - see the documentation on how to use it at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataExport.html

This process does **not** consume your table's read capacity, which removes this concern entirely.

Comment: When I will export data using this new feature will it run any emr cluster as in case of data pipeline.

Comment: No, this is a serverless feature that requires no additional infrastructure

Comment: The exported data is in encrypted format and is compressed. So this data cannot be used directly to read the records from s3 objects. It can be used for data backup.